# Upgrading MVC-3 to MVC-4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Before posting this, I did read [here](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253806) and [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853330/converting-a-asp-net-mvc-3-project-to-mvc-4) -

I took a little different approach, which seems easier.

Since MVC-3 application contained very few controllers and views. I created a new **MVC-4 - Basic application** and copied following files -

1. Controllers
2. Views
3. Layout files
4. Routing info from old Global.asax.cs to App_Start/Route.Config

The advantage I see with this approach is

1. There was no need to refer new Dlls manually.
2. There was no need to update Web.config references.

Build goes fine, however while running the application I end up with following error.

> [A]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection cannot be cast
> to [B]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection.
>
> Type A
> originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context
> 'Default' at location
> 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'.
>
> Type B originates from 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' in the context
> 'Default' at location
> 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Razor\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'.

Obviously somewhere MVC3 dlls are being referred. But not sure where? Any advice on this would be helpful. Thanks !

Comment: How about the web.config within `~/Views`. Did you copy the entire folder and overwrite the mvc4 file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I had to guess, I'd say your `~/Views/web.config` was overwritten and still is pointing to the older razor parser (and subsequently the older config section). Try replacing that file with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
            <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>

    <system.web.webPages.razor>
        <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            </namespaces>
        </pages>
    </system.web.webPages.razor>

    <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    </appSettings>

    <system.web>
        <httpHandlers>
            <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
        </httpHandlers>

        <!--
        Enabling request validation in view pages would cause validation to occur
        after the input has already been processed by the controller. By default
        MVC performs request validation before a controller processes the input.
        To change this behavior apply the ValidateInputAttribute to a
        controller or action.
    -->
        <pages
            validateRequest="false"
            pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
            pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
            userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <controls>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
            </controls>
        </pages>
    </system.web>

    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

        <handlers>
            <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
            <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: how to upgrade a mvc4 application to mvc5, we already upgraded to VS 2013, do i need to first upgrade to mvc4 and then to mvc 5

Comment: Upgrade the nugget packages for mvc.