# Errors when trying to upgrade an existing MVC3 project to MVC4

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am new to Asp.net and Visual Studio. I am developing a web application. I initially did it using MVC3 but i need to upgrade it to mvc4 now. I have tried lots of methods. From updating the files in the current project, to creating a new mvc4 webapp and then copying my models/controllers/views in it. I am aware of various links available on the internet.

In fact i tried the process that is mentioned on asp.net whitepapers as well http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253806

Tried the solution in this link too: [Converting a ASP.NET MVC 3 Project to MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853330/converting-a-asp-net-mvc-3-project-to-mvc-4)

But it has been to no avail. 
The errors I keep getting are follows:

**1.** It first started with the error below:

```
[A]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection cannot be cast to [B]System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection.
```

I initially deleted the razor 4_02 from GAC folder and tried, but that failed. Then after i resolved that by managing the packages.config and making changes in web.config it did go away.

**2.** However, after doing this, when i started the web app, it showed a new error, as below:

```
'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
```

Now, according to what i read online, i uninstalled the Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc using Nuget and then installed package Razor-3.3.0 which failed. Afterwards, I installed package Razor-2.1.0 which was mentioned as a workaround in one of the responses online. And after that i installed Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc again. It was successful.

**3.** Again, when i ran the web app, this time it popped up a new error. This time the error was as below:

```
Compilation Error at '/'
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0
```

I resolved this by removing the unused references as mentioned in one of the responses online. I also changed from System.Web.Webpages.Razor to System.Web.Razor

**4.** After solving that now it is showing me the error as below:

```
No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name    'System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file.
```

Tried solution the links below:

[Error: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21641435/error-no-entity-framework-provider-found-for-the-ado-net-provider-with-invarian)

[No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19821284/no-entity-framework-provider-found-for-the-ado-net-provider-with-invariant-name)

**5.** I also got an error initially

```
error CS1705: Assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' uses 'System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
```

I solved it using the solution given in the link below:

[aspnet_compiler finding wrong version of System.Web.WebPages 1.0.0.0 instead of 2.0.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402005/aspnet-compiler-finding-wrong-version-of-system-web-webpages-1-0-0-0-instead-of)

I have tried changing the provider in the web.config and then i have also tried getting SqlServereCe4.0 dependencies when Visual Studio suggested that. It has been useless.

**Apart from all the errors, i get warnings too.**

As soon as i provide a provider, It shows a warning mentioning that

```
The element 'entityFramework' has invalid child element 'providers'. List of possible elements expected: 'contexts'
```

Another warning that I get:

```
The 'packages' element is not declared.
```

I have tried creating a packages.xsd file and then mapping that, but then it shows me another warning for packages.xsd mentioning that the xmlns can not contain text.

I have been trying for hours, but the problem does not seem to solve. Please help.
I do not know what is going on. How can i upgrade it to MVC4??

Comment: I've found it's easier to create a new project and just move your files over.

Comment: @Will I have tried exactly that like i mentioned above. I created a new Mvc4 project and moved my files, but that has not helped as well.

Comment: Try it again, move one file, compile, move a few more, compile, etc until you find which one is causing the issue.

Comment: @Will I tried, the build is successful but it pops up the same error as i mentioned in #4.

Comment: Have you done what it says in #4?

Comment: @Will I did, but the issue remains. I simply commented it out after looking at a new Mvc4 application's config file where it wasnt given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying everything and getting no where, I used the auto-update tool that upgrades an mvc3 project to mvc4. It does come with lot of references that you might not really need, but hey it worked perfectly and I was able to run my app. 
If you are worried about the unused references/libs, maybe you can reverse engineer and go about removing them one by one. 
The link for the tool is as below:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/UpgradeMvc3ToMvc4