# How do I add ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Application in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-3

How do I add ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Application in Visual Studio 2013?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry. Only MVC4 or newer is [supported in Visual Studios 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266747.aspx)

If you have a project you wish to open in VS2013, you need to [convert it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853330/converting-a-asp-net-mvc-3-project-to-mvc-4)

Comment: I am learning basics of ASP.NET MVC. And I want to follow thi article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620197/Learning-MVC-Part-Creating-MVC-Application-and-P

Comment: but it tells to create MVC 3 web application. I am sure I will get lost somewhere If I use MVC 4. If options and diagrams does not match up with the article as I am a begineer.

Comment: I want to learn creating basic ASP.NET MVC page and adding CRUD operation to it using LINQ to SQL.

Comment: I not 100% sure, but I don't think mvc3 makes any huge strides away from mv4 and I think you'll probably be fine. [There are Newer Tutorials](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4), in fact learning EF is probably better than LtS (imho) . I suppose you could always [downgrade your ide](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30669)

Comment: Actually I am enrolled in a course. And it requires me to do above mentioned assignments as lab. So I need to learn it. :)

Comment: Okey. I will start with MVC 4 and try to simulate as per the article. :) Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I can't recommend much. I checked that one out a while ago and it seemed fine, I would also recommend the mvc4 pluralsight course if you have that service.